# Is it possible to inherit from javascript Function object?

Tags: javascript, function, inheritance, object, invoke

Is it possible to make my own function implementation in javascript? To have javascript object like php object with __invoke magic method?

```
  A = function(){};
  A.prototype = new Function();

  var a = new A();
  alert( a instanceof Function ); // true
  a(); // exception
```

Can't answer my own question... There is an answer:

Sorry for everebody, but I have found good way for my task (I was in several steps away from answer when posted question). I don't delete question, hope somebody will spend less time then me.

```
  A = function()
  {
    var f = function() { alert( 'f called' ) };
    f.__proto__ = A.prototype;
    return f;
  };

  A.prototype = Function( );
  A.prototype.method = function() { alert( 'method called' ) };

  var a = new A();
  alert( a instanceof Function ); // true
  alert( a instanceof A ); // true
  a(); // f called
  a.method(); // method called
```

If it is newbie question pls send me email and I will delete it. Thank you!

Comment: What for? What's lacking with simply making `a` a function with the required behaviour?

Comment: Read this http://www.crockford.com/javascript/inheritance.html

Comment: @Leo Your solution won't work in IE since that browser doesn't implement `__proto__`. Also, note that `__proto__` is non-standard and that it's being **deprecated**, so it's probably not a good idea to rely on it...

Comment: @ŠimeVidas word on the  street is `__proto__` might be making it to IE eventually (although maybe not mutable `__proto__`)

Comment: Coffee Script [allow to do it](http://coffeescript.org/#classes) in a pretty nice way I think.

Comment: @GGG A read-only version of `__proto__` already exists in ECMAScript: `Object.getPrototypeOf()` (and it's implemented in IE9). The thing is that there is no standard way to write the prototype link (to manually redirect the prototype link after the object has been created). `__proto__` enables that, but I think they didn't standardize it in ES5 for a reason (so I assume it's a bad practice). Even reading the prototype link via `Object.getPrototypeOf()` should be avoided according to Crockford.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas I mean let's continue this discussion [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/javascript) if you like :)

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be nice? There's no good way to do it, unfortunately.

The issue, as you have probably noticed, is that setting a function as a constructor function's `prototype` and then invoking the constructor function with `new` results in a plain old object, not a callable function object.

There is one possible semi-workaround, depending on what you need this for. It's an interesting trick, but *probably not a good idea for real-world use*. You can create an iframe and grab the `Function` from the iframe's window. Now you have a "copy" of `Function` that you can do whatever you want to without dirtying up your "real" `Function` function.

```
var frame = document.createElement('iframe');
frame.id = frame.name = 'hacks';
frame.style.zIndex = '-1';
document.appendChild(frame);
var MyFunction = frames['hacks'].Function;
// add stuff to MyFunction and MyFunction.prototype
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
function MyFunction ( f ) {
    _.extend( f, MyFunction.prototype );
    return f;
};

MyFunction.prototype.method = function () {
    alert( 'method called' );
};

var func = MyFunction( function () {
    alert( 'function called' );
});
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/nZczW/

So, you create your custom functions by passing them to your custom function constructor:

```
var func = MyFunction( function () {...} );
```

The methods are defined (normally) on the constructor's prototype:

```
MyFunction.prototype.foo = function () {...};
```

Inside the constructor, the methods are assigned directly on the function itself. (I used underscore.js's `_.extend()`). So, your functions still inherit directly from `Function.prototype`.

You can of course simplify this pattern:

```
var methods = { /* hash of methods */ };

var func = _.extend( function () { ... }, methods );
```